# Setting permissions for AWS API Gateway to HTTP Proxy to Elasticsearch

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-api-gateway, aws-elasticsearch

I am trying to use API Gateway to validate API keys, and then proxy to an AWS Elasticsearch cluster. I used HTTP {proxy+} mode to successfully do this by leaving Elasticsearch open to the public internet. But I want Elasticsearch to not be available except through the API Gateway, and I can't figure out a way to set the access controls. It's looking like I'll have to resort to using a Lambda to do the proxying but I had been hoping to avoid this and so I'm wondering if there's a way to set the access control policies to use the HTTP {proxy+} approach with appropriate access control.